# Save Toggle position on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using localStorage for the dark/light mode toggle on my wordpress site on localhost. Everything works as expected, but the toggle position always reverts to "light" when the page is refreshed or a different page is visited.

This is the code I'm using:

```
(function() {
  let onpageLoad = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "";
  let element = document.body;
  element.classList.add(onpageLoad);
  document.getElementById("theme").textContent =
    localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light";
})();

function themeToggle() {
  let element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");

  let theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
  if (theme && theme === "dark-mode") {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "");
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark-mode");
  }

  document.getElementById("theme").textContent = localStorage.getItem("theme");
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="slider-div">
   <span class="slider-text">Light Mode</span>
   <label class="switch">
     <input type="checkbox" onclick="themeToggle()" id="theme">
     <span class="slider round"></span>
   </label>
   <span class="slider-text">Dark Mode</span>
</div>
```

Here is the the CSS that I used for the checkbox:

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 54px;
  height: 22px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;    
  background-color: #CCC;
  -webkit-transition: .6s;
  transition: .6s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  left: 7px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: .6s;
  transition: .6s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `value` property of the checkbox:

```js
document.getElementById("theme").checked = localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark-mode";
```

Note that this code needs to run *after the checkbox element is processed*. I would suggest inserting a `<script>` element right after the checkbox element with this code.

Comment: Implemented your answer, but now the toggle doesn't move at all. The dark theme can be turned off or on though, just the toggle isn't moving.

Comment: Are you using a "vanilla" checkbox input?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "vanilla" but the above HTML is the one I'm using.

Comment: Well, the code should work... I'm not sure what is the toggle that moves. Normally an `<input type="checkbox">` is, well, a checkbox.

Comment: Oh, I styled the checkbox, so it looks like a toggle. (Switches from off to on or vice versa)

Comment: Right, so you styled it with `:checked`? Did you use JavaScript for that?

Comment: I added the CSS that I used to the original post

Comment: Nevermind. (I think) I found the problem and edited my answer. I was using `value` instead of `checked`...

Comment: Still having the same issue, the toggle isn't moving.

Comment: How did you make the toggle move? I see nothing in your code that does that.

Comment: Here is where I got the toggle https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

Comment: Try to add `document.getElementById("theme").checked = theme === "dark-mode"` at the end of `themeToggle()`.

Comment: Toggle works again, but now we're back to square 1, which is my original question. the toggle just goes to light mode whenever the page is refreshed or a new page is visited.

Comment: I edited my question and replaced `dark` with `dark-mode`. Everything should work then.

Comment: My apologies. Just tried with a "vanilla" checkbox and  <script>
  document.getElementById("theme").checked = localStorage.getItem("theme") === "dark-mode";
</script>

works. Thanks!